# How to find the 2nd occurence of a string and then delete a line 2 lines below that occurence

Tags: perl, awk, sed

I have an xml file that I would like to find the 2nd occurrence of a string and then remove a line 2 lines down from the string.  Here is a sample of how it looks:

```
<application>
    <app>
       <Name>Tester</Name>
       <Class>tester.update</Class>
       <const>
            <argument>READ_ONLY</argument>
       </const>
       <role>sysad</role>
</application>

<application>
    <app>
       <Name>Tester</Name>
       <Class>tester.update</Class>
       <const>
             <argument>READ_ONLY</argument>
       </const>
       <role>tester</role>
</application>
```

Here is what I want it to look like:

```
<application>
    <app>
       <Name>Tester</Name>
       <Class>tester.update</Class>
       <const>
            <argument>READ_ONLY</argument>
       </const>
       <role>sysad</role>
</application>
.
.
.
<application>
    <app>
       <Name>Tester</Name>
       <Class>tester.update</Class>
       <const>
       </const>
       <role>tester</role>
</application>
```

The argument tags should be completely removed from the 2nd instance

I'm searching for `tester.update` and then attempting to remove the line that is 2 lines down on the 2nd occurrence of tester.update

I've attempted doing something like:

```
sed -i 'tester.update/{p;N;d}' file.txt
```

but this removes the 2nd line from both instances of `tester.update.`

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: [You can't parse \[X\]HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you don't have an XML parser:

sed is for doing s/old/new on individual lines, **that is all**. For anything else you should be using awk, e.g. with any awk in any shell on every UNIX box you can clearly and simply just do:

```
$ awk '/tester.update/{if (++cnt==2) skip=NR+2} NR!=skip' file
<application>
    <app>
       <Name>Tester</Name>
       <Class>tester.update</Class>
       <const>
            <argument>READ_ONLY</argument>
       </const>
       <role>sysad</role>
</application>

<application>
    <app>
       <Name>Tester</Name>
       <Class>tester.update</Class>
       <const>
       </const>
       <role>tester</role>
</application>
```

Want to find the 127th occurrence of `tester.update` instead of the 2nd? Just change `cnt==2` to `cnt==127`. Want to delete the 93rd line after that is found instead of the 2nd? Just change `skip=NR+2` to `skip=NR+93`. Try making trivial changes like that (or anything else!) to a sed solution.

Like sed for the brevity? You can sacrifice clarity for brevity in awk too:

```
$ awk '/tester.update/&&++c==2{s=NR+2}NR!=s' file
<application>
    <app>
       <Name>Tester</Name>
       <Class>tester.update</Class>
       <const>
            <argument>READ_ONLY</argument>
       </const>
       <role>sysad</role>
</application>

<application>
    <app>
       <Name>Tester</Name>
       <Class>tester.update</Class>
       <const>
       </const>
       <role>tester</role>
</application>
```

but importantly **you don't have to** and, finally, if you like GNU sed for inplace editing with `-i`, GNU awk has the same with `-i inplace`.

Comment: Ed, I do really like your solution.  It's amazing to me how many different ways there are to achieve a result.  I'm looking at my gnu awk and there isn't a -i option that I can see.  I have version 3.1.8.  Maybe the version is too old.

Comment: @chadopp yes that's **extremely** old, e.g. about 5 years out of date. The current version is 5.0.1 and has a ton of great functionality and a few bug fixes missing from 3.1.8. In any case, you can always do `awk 'script' file > tmp && mv tmp file` - that's exactly what `sed -i`, `perl -i`, `awk -i inplace`, and every other "inplace editing" tool (except `ed` which uses an internal buffer the size of your input file) do in the background anyway.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately these systems are on a baseline that I can change at the moment.  Really appreciate your input and help

Comment: Yes there are lots of alternatives and when deciding between sed and awk, to help you pick the right one just imagine yourself coming across the 2 scripts in your code 6 months from now and having to debug or enhance it. Which one would you rather be faced with? There's obviously also portability (the awk one will work with any awk in any shell on every UNIX box), efficiency, etc. If it's anything other than a simple `s/old/new` sed is just for the mental exercise.

Comment: Yes that is definitely worth considering.  The awk solution is simpler to understand.

Comment: And easier to enhance and to port to a new machine and more efficient and.... Leave the sed answer as accepted if you like, I could care less, but for your own sake just use the awk script in your actual code. You'll thank yourself later :-)!

Comment: I think the awk solution works better for what I’m doing so thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A Perl solution would be much simpler with an XML parser. Here's what it might look like with [Mojo::DOM](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM), which finds tags using [CSS rules](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM::CSS):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Mojo::DOM;
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';

my $xml = do { local $/; <> };
my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new->xml(1)->parse($xml);
$dom->at('application:nth-of-type(2) > app > const')->content('');
print $dom->to_string;
```

Results in:

```
<application>
    <app>
       <Name>Tester</Name>
       <Class>tester.update</Class>
       <const>
            <argument>READ_ONLY</argument>
       </const>
       <role>sysad</role>
</app></application>

<application>
    <app>
       <Name>Tester</Name>
       <Class>tester.update</Class>
       <const />
       <role>tester</role>
</app></application>
```

(It even fixed the missing close tag for `<app>`)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The app tag missing was my fat finger typo.  It looks like the code also removed the <const> open tag which would break the XML.

Comment: @chadopp `<const />` is valid XML and essentially means the same as `<const></const>`.

Comment: You can replace the contents with space characters if you really want to keep the tag separated out. `->content("\n")` or `->content(' ')`

Comment: Or you can more surgically just remove the `<argument>` tag, leaving surrounding whitespace: `->at('argument')->remove;`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -Ei '/tester.update/{x;s/^/x/;/^x{2}$/{;x;n;n;d};x}' file
```

Each time the string `tester.update` in seen, increment a counter in the hold space. If that counter contains 2, swap back to the current line, print it and the next line and delete the following one.

Comment: This does exactly what I want.  Thanks for taking the time to write this  up.